# Set many variables to 0 in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I was just wondering if there is an special method or call to set many variables to 0. I have like 20 and the code looks very ugly because i have them aligned like this:

```
x=0;
y=0;
z=0;
etc...
```

Since there are so many handy functions I thought there might be.

Thanks

PD: I'm using Objective C, Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're the same type (or are coercible to the same type), then you can always do:

```
x = y = z = 0;
```

It's essentially the same thing, but horizontal :-)

Comment: Oh lol so easy, never thought of it. Then again I dont really get the difference between objective c and c (other than on seems to be more object oriented). No idea what the super set of, means.

Comment: In this case, Objective-C is a super-set of C because it contains all of the features of C (all of it's feature "set"), but adds some more of its own (e.g. object-oriented programming features) - its feature "set" contains all of C's, plus some more. If you're interested, it's all to do with [set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is C, so if C can say: `x = y = z = 0;` so can Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using NSArray, `which you can't with primitives types`.
So this answer don't apply to your example,
But if you got an NSArray of element you have the following method that can be very useful.

> Sending Messages to Elements
>   – makeObjectsPerformSelector:
>   – makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:
>   – enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
>   – enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:
>   – enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:options:usingBlock:

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If your variables have the same type and need uniform treatment throughout, you can unite them into an array (not a NSArray, a primitive array) and use memset() to zero it out.

If they're of different integer types and have the same lifetime and visibility, you can make them a structure and use memset().

If they are all integers, and happen to be ivars in an Objective C class, they're zeroed out on class initialization.

If the only thing in common is that they need to be zeroed out at the same time, don't be lazy and write an `a = b = c = 0` line.